# Can I solicit upvotes for my community advert?

Tags: support, advertising

Is it bad form to solicit upvotes from external sites for my community advert from people who are quite probably SO members?

I have an open source advert proposal on one site, and would like to spread to word to help it, there's another community I'm well respected/known in (poor them) who are likely to be SO members so is that ok?

I'm not advocating spamming, just well placed messages to get some support is all :)  And just checking it's all considered to be OK.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything fundamentally wrong with this - the users need to *somewhat* active on one of the sites to have the privilege to vote, so you're not gaming the system in any way.

However, I would find it fitting if the community you do this in were *somehow* related to the project you want to advertise. Say, if you tell all your friends in the Zorgblorg community (Zorgblorg being a Open source project of some sort) to come vote for the Zorblorg SO ad, that is 100% okay.

If it's just some unrelated community you happen to be well known in, so users go vote just because their mate Tim asked them to, it would have a slightly unfair taste to it. Nobody can prohibit you from rallying support that way, but it would be nicer not to do it.